# Calculate percentage in SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data and I am trying to find the percentage of purchases on weekdays vs weekends in ORACLE SQL per ID

| ID | DAY | total per day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | weekday | 78 |
| 1 | weekend | 20 |
| 2 | weekday | 13 |
| 2 | weekend | 37 |

The output i am expecting is:

| ID | DAY | percentage per day |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | weekday | 79 |
| 1 | weekend | 20 |
| 2 | weekday | 26 |
| 2 | weekend | 74 |

the percentage is calculated by the ( total per day / sum (total per day) ) for each ID. what is the best way to do it.
Appreciate your help!

Comment: Please, show your current attempt and describe what is the issue with it. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SUM` as an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT id,
       day,
       100 * total_per_day / SUM(total_per_day) OVER (PARTITION BY id)
         AS percentage
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, DAY, total_per_day) AS
SELECT 1, 'weekday', 78 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'weekend', 20 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'weekday', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'weekend', 37 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | ID | DAY | PERCENTAGE |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | weekday | 79.59183673469387755102040816326530612245 |
> | 1 | weekend | 20.40816326530612244897959183673469387755 |
> | 2 | weekday | 26 |
> | 2 | weekend | 74 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8ffb53dc55969ca125c5f7413df7f8a1)*